# GWT Compilation Error - GXT 3.0 , GWT 2.4

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using GWT 2.4.0 with GXT 3.0.0b
I am trying to Google Compile the application, but every time I get this error.

```
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding
  [ERROR] at AddNewCompDtlsForCombo.java(5): class AddNewCompDtlsForCombo 
     com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JClassType
Exception in thread "UnitWriteThread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferToStream(DiskCache.java:182)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken.writeObject(DiskCacheToken.java:91)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at         com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$UnitWriter.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:226)
```

What is the issue? Is it with some missing jars/plugins?
Earlier I was using GWT 2.1 with Gxt 2.4 which used to Compile fine.
Please help

Comment: Been seeing similar issues with 2.5.0 as well - at least in these cases it appears to be too many files open. If using *nix, try increasing the number of files a process can have open at a time.

Comment: as an addition to @ColinAlworth's comment, assuming compilation on a *nix machine, try increasing the allowed shared resources by setting `ulimit`, as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/PxMvonuisVU).

Comment: I've also seen similar problems from either corrupt jars (check SHA hash) or a full /tmp folder.  Delete your gwt-unitCache in project folder (if the cache gets to big, it will lock up your ability to compile), purge your temp files, and investigate the ulimit matter mentioned above...

Comment: I cleared gwt-unitCache, also all the temp files. It didn't help. I had to setup a new workspace again, and it works fine now. Thanks all 4 help :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this page: https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.1/getting_started/Versions.html

GWT 2.4.0 may be incompatible with GXT 3.0.0b. Switching to GWT 2.5.1 should help.